# D3.js Process Diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am very new to D3.js. Please note that version 4 is being used.

## .HTML file

(a lot derived from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>

<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="d3.js"></script>
<script>

var treeData =
  {
    "name": "File 1",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "File 2",
        "children": [
          { "name": "File 3",
            "subprocess": [
                {"name": "File 4"}],
            "children" : [
                { "name": "File 5" } ]

          },
          ]
      }
    ]
  };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 0, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 25},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750, // time between transitions (interaction)
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = 0;
console.log(root);

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);  

  console.log(treeData.descendants());

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", "2em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? 13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "start" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            L ${d.y} ${d.x}`;

    return path;
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}

</script>
</body>
```

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

The font isn't quite the same, but I hope the idea is clear: essentially, I want to create arrows and for the File 4 to show up as above. I might be formatting the `JSON` incorrectly; if this is the case, please let me know it should be best formatted.

In general, each (first-level) `child` should point to the right, each `subprocess` should point downward, and any `child` contained in a `subprocess` should point downward as well.

Comment: What happens if there are multiple sub-processes?

Comment: @approxiblue Excellent question. There is only one subprocess per first-level child, at most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**

Thinking about this last night and I decided my naive approach is to hackish and brute-force.  The problem is that by introducing a second array of children (the subprocess array) and placing those nodes directly, you lose the magic of `d3.tree`.  You lose it's ability to walk the parent/child relationship and determine the link structure.  Instead I propose you keep the single array of children and mark those as a subprocess with an additional property.  The data structure would look like this:

```
var treeData = {
  "name": "File 1",
  "children": [{
    "name": "File 2",
    "children": [{
      "name": "File 3",
      "children": [{
        "name": "File 5"
      }, {
        "name": "File 4",
        "type": "subprocess", //<-- this is a subprocess with children
        "children": [{
          "name": "File 6"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
};
```

Then you preprocess the data to determine at which depth the subprocess node is; much in the same way `d3.tree` marks nodes at specific depths.

```
root.data['depthToSub'] = 0;
isChildOfProcess(root.children, 0);

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

function isChildOfProcess(children, depth) {
  children.forEach(function(d) {
    d.data['depthToSub'] = depth;
    if (d.data.type && d.data.type === "subprocess") {
      d.data['depthToSub'] = 1;
      isChildOfProcess(d.children, 2);
    } else if (depth > 0 && d.children) {
      isChildOfProcess(d.children, ++depth);
    } else if (d.children) {
      isChildOfProcess(d.children, 0);
    }
  })
}
```

After this processing you can then "fix" the coordinates the `d3.tree` generates to create your right-angled structure:

```
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {

    d.y = d.depth * 180;

    if (d.parent) {
      d.x = d.parent.x;
    }

    if (d.data.depthToSub) {
      d.y = d.parent.y;
      d.x = (d.data.depthToSub * nodes[0].x) + nodes[0].x;
    }
  });
```

The drawing then just uses the same code you had before.  Here's a running sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    .arrow {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var treeData = {
      "name": "File 1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "File 2",
        "children": [{
          "name": "File 3",
          "children": [{
            "name": "File 5"
          }, {
            "name": "File 4",
            "type": "subprocess",
            "children": [{
              "name": "File 6",
              "children": [{
                "name": "File 7"
              }]
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }]
    };

     // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
    var margin = {
        top: 0,
        right: 90,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 25
      },
      width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

     // append the svg object to the body of the page
     // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
     // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var defs = svg.append("defs");

    defs
      .append("marker")
      .attr("id", "arrow")
      .attr("class", "arrow")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -4 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 12)
      .attr("refY", 0)
      .attr("markerWidth", 12)
      .attr("markerHeight", 12)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-4L8,0L0,4");

    var i = 0,
      duration = 750, // time between transitions (interaction)
      root;

     // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    var treemap = d3.tree().size([200, width]);

     // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
    root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
      return d.children;
    });
    root.x0 = 0;
    root.y0 = 0;

    root.data['depthToSub'] = 0;
    isChildOfProcess(root.children, 0);

     // Collapse after the second level
    root.children.forEach(collapse);

    function isChildOfProcess(children, depth) {
      children.forEach(function(d) {
        d.data['depthToSub'] = depth;
        if (d.data.type && d.data.type === "subprocess") {
          d.data['depthToSub'] = 1;
          isChildOfProcess(d.children, 2);
        } else if (depth > 0 && d.children) {
          isChildOfProcess(d.children, ++depth);
        } else if (d.children) {
          isChildOfProcess(d.children, 0);
        }
      })
    }

     // Collapse after the second level
    root.children.forEach(collapse);

    update(root);

     // Collapse the node and all it's children
    function collapse(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children
        d._children.forEach(collapse)
        d.children = null
      }
    }

    function update(source) {

      // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
      var treeData = treemap(root);

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
        links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

      nodes.forEach(function(d) {

        d.y = d.depth * 180;

        if (d.parent) {
          d.x = d.parent.x;
        }

        if (d.data.depthToSub) {
          d.y = d.parent.y;
          d.x = (d.data.depthToSub * nodes[0].x) + nodes[0].x;
        }
      });

      // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

      // Update the nodes...
      var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
          return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

      // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on('click', click);

      // Add Circle for the nodes
      nodeEnter.append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('r', 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      // Add labels for the nodes
      nodeEnter.append('text')
        .attr("dy", "2em")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? 13 : 13;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "start" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.data.name;
        });

      // UPDATE
      var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

      // Transition to the proper position for the node
      nodeUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });

      // Update the node attributes and style
      nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
        .attr('r', 10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        })
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


      // Remove any exiting nodes
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();

      // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
      nodeExit.select('circle')
        .attr('r', 1e-6);

      // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
      nodeExit.select('text')
        .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

      // ****************** links section ***************************

      // Update the links...
      var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
        .data(links, function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
          }
          return diagonal(o, o)
        })
        .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
          return "url(#arrow)";
        });

      // UPDATE
      var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

      // Transition back to the parent element position
      linkUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          return diagonal(d, d.parent)
        });

      // Remove any exiting links
      var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
          }
          return diagonal(o, o)
        })
        .remove();

      // Store the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });

      // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
      function diagonal(s, d) {

        path = `M ${d.y} ${d.x}
            L ${s.y} ${s.x}`;

        return path;
      }

      // Toggle children on click.
      function click(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**OLD ANSWER**

The naive approach is to check each entering node to see if it has a subprocess and then add the additional elements at that time:

```
nodeEnter.each(function(d){
  if (d.data.subprocess){
    var sp = d3.select(this).append('g')
      .datum(d)
      .attr('class','subprocess');

    sp.append('path')
      .attr('d', 'M0,' + (-d.x - subProcessDist) + 'L0,0')
      .style('stroke', '#ccc')
      .style('stroke-width', '2px')
      .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
        return "url(#arrow)";
      });

    sp.append('circle')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style('fill', '#fff');

    sp.append('text')
      .attr('x', 13)
      .style('text-anchor', 'start')
      .text(function(d){
        return d.data.subprocess[0].name;
      });
  }
});
```

The arrow heads can be added using the conventional marker approach shown [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278).

```
var defs = svg.append("defs");

defs
  .append("marker")
  .attr("id", "arrow")
  .attr("class", "arrow")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -4 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 12)
  .attr("refY", 0)
  .attr("markerWidth", 12)
  .attr("markerHeight", 12)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-4L8,0L0,4");

...

// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr('d', function(d) {
    var o = {
      x: source.x0,
      y: source.y0
    }
    return diagonal(o, o)
  })
  .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
    return "url(#arrow)";
  });
```

Here's full running code with these changes and others to put it all together:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    
    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    .arrow{
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
  
    var subProcessDist = 15;
  
    var treeData = {
      "name": "File 1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "File 2",
        "children": [{
          "name": "File 3",
          "subprocess": [{
            "name": "File 4"
          }],
          "children": [{
            "name": "File 5"
          }]

        }, ]
      }]
    };

    // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
    var margin = {
        top: 0,
        right: 90,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 25
      },
      width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
      
    var defs = svg.append("defs");
    
    defs
      .append("marker")
      .attr("id", "arrow")
      .attr("class", "arrow")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -4 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 12)
      .attr("refY", 0)
      .attr("markerWidth", 12)
      .attr("markerHeight", 12)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-4L8,0L0,4");
      
    var i = 0,
      duration = 750, // time between transitions (interaction)
      root;

    // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

    // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
    root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
      return d.children;
    });
    root.x0 = 0;
    root.y0 = 0;
    //console.log(root);

    // Collapse after the second level
    root.children.forEach(collapse);

    update(root);

    // Collapse the node and all it's children
    function collapse(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children
        d._children.forEach(collapse)
        d.children = null
      }
    }

    function update(source) {

      // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
      var treeData = treemap(root);

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
        links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180
      });

      // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

      // Update the nodes...
      var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
          return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

      // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on('click', click);
        
      nodeEnter.each(function(d){

          if (d.data.subprocess){
            var sp = d3.select(this).append('g')
              .datum(d)
              .attr('class','subprocess');
              
            sp.append('path')
              .attr('d', 'M0,' + (-d.x - subProcessDist) + 'L0,0')
              .style('stroke', '#ccc')
              .style('stroke-width', '2px')
              .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
                return "url(#arrow)";
              });
              
            sp.append('circle')
              .attr('r', 1e-6)
              .style('fill', '#fff');
              
            sp.append('text')
              .attr('x', 13)
              .style('text-anchor', 'start')
              .text(function(d){
                return d.data.subprocess[0].name;
              });
          }
        });

      // Add Circle for the nodes
      nodeEnter.append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('r', 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      // Add labels for the nodes
      nodeEnter.append('text')
        .attr("dy", "2em")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? 13 : 13;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "start" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.data.name;
        });

      // UPDATE
      var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

      // Transition to the proper position for the node
      nodeUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });
        
      nodeUpdate.select('.subprocess')
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + (0) + "," + (d.x + subProcessDist) + ")";
        });
      nodeUpdate.select('.subprocess').select('circle').attr('r', 10);

      // Update the node attributes and style
      nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
        .attr('r', 10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        })
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


      // Remove any exiting nodes
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();

      // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
      nodeExit.selectAll('circle')
        .attr('r', 1e-6);

      // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
      nodeExit.selectAll('text')
        .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

      // ****************** links section ***************************

      // Update the links...
      var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
        .data(links, function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
          }
          return diagonal(o, o)
        })
        .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
          return "url(#arrow)";
        });

      // UPDATE
      var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

      // Transition back to the parent element position
      linkUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          return diagonal(d, d.parent)
        });

      // Remove any exiting links
      var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
          }
          return diagonal(o, o)
        })
        .remove();

      // Store the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });

      // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
      function diagonal(s, d) {

        path = `M ${d.y} ${d.x}
            L ${s.y} ${s.x}`;

        return path;
      }

      // Toggle children on click.
      function click(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have a double,although i'm new to it but whenever i click the all files generated and then i click `file 2` then `file 4` gets appended to the `file 5` and with `file 3` synchronously

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I only have one more question: I tried inserting a `children` within a `subprocess` and it is not showing up. Perhaps I formatted the JSON incorrectly? `var treeData = {
        "name": "File 2",
        "children": [{
          "name": "File 3",
          "subprocess": [{
            "name": "File 4",
   "children": [{
    "name": "File 6"
   }]
          }],
          "children": [{
            "name": "File 5"
          }]

        }, ]
    };`

Comment: @Clarinetist, hmm, can it be assumed that a sub-process will only ever have one child?

Comment: @Mark A sub-process can have (theoretically) an unlimited amount of children. Regardless, every child contained in a subprocess should be pointing down from the subprocess node.

Comment: @Clarinetist, re-wrote my answer completely.  I think the new approach is a lot more sound and less hacky.

Comment: Thank you. The solution is very useful. I can put this as a new question, if you prefer, but if I wanted to keep adding nodes below `File 6`, how would I go about doing this? Inserting a `children` level seems to not change the `x` and `y` value of the new node and places it on top of the `File 6` node.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was something going on with the `depthtoSub` when I was trying to sort this out. I appreciate the time you've put into this. Thanks again!

Comment: @Clarinetist, turning out to be a complicated, cool piece of code.  Let me know if it needs further tweaking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132919/discussion-between-clarinetist-and-mark).